# Excel formulas to work on cells with prefix

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to figure out quite a simple solution to make excel either include cells with prefix in the formula or split the cell into two and use the number in the formula.

```
SC16    1.00--1.00--1.00--1.00
SC17    *2.0--3.00--4.00-*5
SC18    2.00--3.00--4.00--5.00
SC19    2.00-*3 *4--5.00--0.00
SC20    *2.0--3.00--4.00--5.00
```

sc16-20 =SUM(B1:B5) =SUM(C1:C5) =SUM(D1:D5) =SUM(E1:E5)

[formulas in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3X2F.png)

How can I make this work?

Comment: Do you always have the same prefix (i.e. the asterisk here) ? If you don't, do you always have the same number of characters of the prefix ? Or, can your prefix be anything ?

Comment: Couldn't you simply use a find and replace to remove the prefixes?

Comment: @mr.mams it's always an asterisk. and it has to be there can't remove it as its used for data analysis down the line

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1: cleanse the data into a new column and sum on it**

1. Copy the following formula in a new column for converting all values to numbers (let's say you paste it in F1, and then you drag it up to F5)

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B1); B1; NUMBERVALUE(REPLACE(B1;1;1;"")))
```

2. Sum the cells in that new column (i.e. with the formula below in F6)

```
=SUM(F1:F5)
```

Thus, the column F will contain the cleansed values for column B.

**BONUS**: After that, you can even drag F1-F6 cells to the right, in order to get the same for C, D and E columns.

**Solution 2: Split into two columns (one with the asterisks if any, and the other one with the numbers only)**

Same as above + paste the formula below in the column that will contain the asterisks if any

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B1); ""; MID(B1; 1; 1))
```

Comment: Hey @mr.mams that's great but not exactly what I meant. I need to keep the * and perform calculations on those numbers keeping the *. So creating a new table without the * doesn't help in this case. (THANKS THO! I'll defo be using that for some things)

Or another option is to split the cell into 2 and have one with * and one just the number.

Comment: I just updated my answer above: please check it out and let me know if that's fine for you